# Uncaught TypeError in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created chatbot using pytorch and integrating it into flask project.
But getting some erros please help me with it. Thanks!

// app.js
app.js file used while creating chatbot

```
class Chatbox {
        constructor() {
            this.args = {
                openButton : document.querySelector('.chatbox__button'),
                closeButton : document.querySelector('.chatbox__support'),
                sendButton : document.querySelector('.send__button')
            }

            this.state = false;
            this.messages = [];
        }

        display() {
            const {openButton, chatBox, sendButton} = this.args;

            openButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleState(chatBox))

            sendButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> this.onSendButton(chatBox))

            const node = chatBox.querySelector('input');
            node.addEventListener("keyup", ({key}) => {
                if (key === "Enter"){
                    this.onSendButton(chatBox)
                }
            })

        }

        toggleState(chatBox){
            this.state = !this.state;

            if(this.state){
                chatBox.classList.add('chatbox--active')
            }else{
                chatBox.classList.remove('chatbox--active')
            }
        }


        onSendButton(chatbox){
            var textField = Chatbox.querySelector('input');
            let text1 = textField.value
            if (text1 === ""){
                return;
            }

            let msg1 = {name : "User", message:text1}
            this.messages.push(msg1);

            fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/predict', {
                method: 'POST',
                body : JSON.stringify({message:text1}),
                mode : 'cors',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
            })

            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                let msg2 = {name: 'Sam', message: r.answer};
                this.messages.push(msg2);
                this.updateChatText(chatbox)
                textField.value = ''

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                this.updateChatText(chatbox)
                textField.value = ''
            });

        }

        updateChatText(chatbox){
            var html = '';
            this.messages.slice().reverse().forEach(function(item,){
                if (item.name === 'Sam'){
                    html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor'> + item.message + '<div>'
                }    
                else{
                    html += 'div class="messages-__item messages__item--operator' + item.message + '<div>'
                } 
            });

            const chatmessage = chatbox.querySelector('.chatbox__messages');
            chatmessage.innerHTML = html;
        }




}


const newChat = new Chatbox();
newChat.display();
```

base.html
frontend file to render chatbot window. But on clicking on icon it does not loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chatbot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="chatbox__support">
            <div class="chatbox__header">
                <div class="chatbox__image--header">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="chatbox__content--header">
                    <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
                    <p class="chatbox__description--header">Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__messages">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__footer">
                <input name="input" type="text" placeholder="Write a message...">
                <button class="chatbox__send--footer send__button">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
            <button><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/chatbox-icon.svg') }}" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
    <script>
        $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson }};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

Im getting the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')
    at Chatbox.display (app.js:20:34)
    at app.js:95:9
```

```
app.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
    at Chatbox.toggleState (app.js:33:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (app.js:16:61)
```

Python chatbot using Pytorch

Comment: `this.args` does not have a "chatBox" property, "openButton", "closeButton", and "sendButton".

Comment: please elaborate it more

Comment: Please provide the codelines of the error

Comment: Why is line 14 (chatBox) and line 5 (closeButton) different?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1: chatBox is `undefined` because `this.args` does't have the chatBox property, you wrote "closeButton" at the 2nd position.

Erorr 2: Again, chatBox is `undefined`.